# How to convert the string as timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, sql-timestamp

```
$current_date=date('Y-m-d');
$time = strtotime("$current_date -0 years -0 months -1 days");
$date = date("Y-m-d", $time)."<BR>";
```

the $date holds 2015-10-08  as value. but when i use this value in sql statement, it does not pull records. i did this.

```
$x=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) from table_name WHERE registration_date='$date'");
$y=mysql_fetch_row($x);
echo $y[0];
```

It does not pull records..  however if i replace $date with 2015-10-08  .. it does fetch a value from sql

Comment: if you replace '$date' with '2015-10-08' do you get results?

Comment: 1.) $x=mysql_query=( -> why is there an equal sign there? 2.) remove the ."<BR>" ....

Comment: Well i do get the results .. if i just put  '2015-10-08' ..
and  there is not = sign there.. it was just a typo .. i'll edit it

Comment: Hi.. i was browsing and i found this...
`$full_date=date('Y-m-d');
$timestring="$full_date";
$datetime=new DateTime($timestring);
$datetime->modify('-7 day');
$yesterday_fulldate= $datetime->format("Y-m-d");`
It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for da help everyone ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Educated guess > you used "echo $date" and didn't noticed it ended with

```
<br>
```

which is an empty newline

use var_dump($date) to see any unneeded newlines,whitespace and tags

Comment: Sure (: click the check icon left of the answer to accept it if it solved your problem.